# how to get the result of column name of a joined table having same column name?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i've joined 4 tables and 3 table have same column name called "Remarks". How can i display the result of Remarks of different tables?
Here is the query

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM setup_candidate AS SC,
                                        setup_candidate_degree AS SCD,
                                        setup_candidate_work_experience AS SCWE,
                                        transaction_counselor_candidate_assignment AS TCCA
                                    WHERE SC.Candidate_No = SCD.Candidate_No 
                                    AND SCD.Candidate_No = SCWE.Candidate_No
                                    AND SCWE.Candidate_No = TCCA.Candidate_ID
                                    AND SC.Candidate_No = '$id' 
                                    ");
                    if(!$qry){ echo "problem"}
```

when i display the result in a page how do i address the specific Remarks Table?

for example i did

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($qry);

echo $row['Remarks'];
```

lets say i want to get the Remarks of setup_candidate_degree table ? Can you help me ? Thanks XD

Comment: you can use alias "AS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add alias for those fields.

   SELECT *, `setup_candidate_degree.Remaks` as `setup_candidate_degree_Remaks`
2. Get by number from `$row` array.

Comment: problemUnknown column 'setup_candidate_degree.Remarks' in 'field list'

Comment: CREATE TABLE `setup_candidate_degree` (
  `SCD_ID` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Candidate_No` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SD_ID` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Score_Obtained` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Out_Of` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Passed_Year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Remarks` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status_Flag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SCD_ID`),

Comment: You do not have this table in your query.

Comment: hi i solved the problem, the thing you should have given hint was
SELECT *, SCD.Remaks as setup_candidate_degree_Remaks beacuase i have already defined the alias for the tablename and the table name won't be recognized

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin, i am happy for you. :^ )